# Запуск phar в cmd с параметрами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Запускаю .phar файл с командной строки:

```
php test.phar some_param
```

Как можно получить "some_param"?
Пытался GET, REQUEST...

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: @Detroys, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[@Detroys](/users/26872/detroys), попробуйте [$argv](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Etki, спасибо, это помогло